# How to pass shell script variable to mysql stored procedure as OUT parameter?

Tags: mysql, sql, shell, sh

I want to pass shell script variable as OUT parameter to Mysql stored proc. Stored proc is like this:

```
SET sql_mode = 'ANSI_QUOTES';
DELIMITER $$
  CREATE PROCEDURE GetTypeSchemaFromAttributeTable(OUT ColumnType VARCHAR (512), OUT ColumnCharset VARCHAR(128), OUT ColumnCollationName VARCHAR(128))
      BEGIN
        SELECT `COLUMN_TYPE` AS ColumnType, `CHARACTER_SET_NAME` AS ColumnCharset, `COLLATION_NAME` AS ColumnCollationName FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='example' AND `TABLE_NAME`='Attribute' AND `COLUMN_NAME`='Type';
      END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then my shell script:

```
mysql --host="blabla" --user="blabla" --password="blabla" --database="blabla" -e "CALL GetTypeSchemaFromAttributeTable(@type, @charset, @collation)"
echo $type
echo $charset
echo $collation
```

But unfortunately, it's not working. All these variables are empty. Could someone suggest what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign output of mysql command to variable and then split it using awk or other utility
Use -sN in mysql to hide column name and table layout

```
output=`mysql --host="blabla" --user="blabla" --password="blabla" --database="blabla"  -sN -e "CALL GetTypeSchemaFromAttributeTable(@type, @charset, @collation)"`

$type=`echo $output | awk '{ print $1 }'`
$charse=`echo $output | awk '{ print $2 }'`
$collation=`echo $output | awk '{ print $3 }'`


echo $type
echo $charset
echo $collation
```

Comment: This is helpful for the OP, but it misses a couple of key pieces of information that might be helpful for their understanding.  Notably: (1) `OUT` parameters bind to the variables in the SQL connection.  There is no relation between `$type` inside of the shell and `@type` inside of the MySQL connection. (2) `SELECT...INTO` is necessary to assign to those parameters.  At present, those parameters are passed in and totally ignored.